# find array value in array column

Tags: php, arrays

i have array like this

```
$data = array(
array('name'=>'Matemathic','SKS'=>5),
array('name'=>'History','SKS'=>2),
array('name'=>'English','SKS'=>3)
);
```

i want to search where name '**History**' and get SKS value

Comment: I guess this PHP code, what is the relationship with sql?

Comment: oh im sorry, this array im get from sql, but in php i want search value in array

Comment: You should handle this in SQL using a query with a where clause.

Comment: any php code to find array ?  ijust find a problem without duplicat sql, with where and without where to find that value

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried to array_search and array_coloumn but not find the problem. im so confused

Comment: Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: thankyou any alternatif for array_search

Comment: Why would you need any when it works perfectly fine. Read through the link I posted, there is an example posted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
array('name'=>'Matemathic','SKS'=>5),
array('name'=>'History','SKS'=>2),
array('name'=>'English','SKS'=>3)
);

foreach($data as $i) {
    if ($i['name'] == 'History') {
        echo $i['SKS'];
        break;
    }
}
```